# What is the ICAO equivalent of a "point out"?

Tags: air-traffic-control, terminology

In FAA air traffic control, when we have an aircraft that is transitioning through someone else's airspace that we want to talk to we do a "point out":

> Point Out. A physical or automated action taken by a controller to transfer the radar identification of an aircraft to another controller if the aircraft will or may enter the airspace or protected airspace of another controller and radio communications will not be transferred. - [source](http://tfmlearning.faa.gov/publications/atpubs/ATC/atc0504.html)

Can anyone please tell me what the equivalent of a point out is in ICAO (with a reference to ICAO Doc 4444 if possible)?

Answer (score 4):

> > We have an aircraft that is transitioning through someone else's airspace that we want to talk to we do a "point out".

Basically you want to grab the attention of the other controller wrt a particular plane that they are controlling (or unaware of), in ICAO 4444 lingo that's a **General Point** message:

> **11.4.2.5.19 GENERAL POINT MESSAGES** The General Point message shall be transmitted to draw the attention of the controller receiving the message to a flight to support voice coordination. The General Point message shall include details of a flight that may have been previously unknown to the receiving unit, to permit it to be displayed if required. This may include, for example, a flight that had planned to operate in airspace under the control of one ATS unit requesting climb or diversion into airspace controlled by another ATS unit which has no details of the flight.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by @mins, it seems this question is about transfer of identification, which is a way for one controlled to identify a track based on an identification already established by another controller.

In this case, the ICAO equivalent of a “point out” is explained in Doc 4444 section 8.6.3.2(e):

> 8.6.3.2 Transfer of identification shall be effected by one of the following methods:
>
> [...]
>
> e) direct designation (pointing with the finger) of the position indication, if the two situation displays are adjacent, or if a common “conference” type of situation display is used;
>
> Note.— Attention must be given to any errors which might occur due to parallax effect

This is mostly a thing of the past, since most tracks today are identified based on SSR or ADS.